# Parsing and storing values from a config file

Tags: c#

I am trying to read through a .cfg file.

I have successfully read values and stored them into a list, and then into a datagrid.

The hard part for me, is this "linekey.INT.option" as you can see below.

```
linekey.6.label = Call Park
linekey.6.line = 1
linekey.6.pickup_value = 
linekey.6.type = 10
linekey.6.value = 70
linekey.7.label = Park 1
linekey.7.line = 1
linekey.7.pickup_value = 71
linekey.7.type = 16
linekey.7.value = 71
linekey.8.label = Park 2
linekey.8.line = 1
linekey.8.pickup_value = 72
linekey.8.type = 16
linekey.8.value = 72
```

I read the config file and add all the linekeys to a dictionary

```
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string line in fileLines)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        tbConfigInput.Text = sb.ToString();

        Dictionary<string, string> getLines = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (string line in tbConfigInput.Lines)
        {
            if (line != "#!version:1.0.0.1")
            {
                if (line != "")
                {
                    if (line.Contains("linekey"))
                    {
                        string[] splitLine = line.Split('=');
                        getLines.Add(splitLine[0], splitLine[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I can then add them to a 2 column list no problem

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> line in getLines)
        {
            ListViewDataItem item = new ListViewDataItem();
            listConfigOptions.Items.Add(item);

            item[0] = line.Key;
            item[1] = line.Value;
        }

        listConfigOptions.Columns[0].BestFit();
        listConfigOptions.Columns[1].BestFit();
```

What I can't seem to do, is take all items that belong to linekey.6 or linekey.7 and add them to their own row in a datatable, ie:

```
Like Key   |    Label     |     Line     |     Extension     |     Type    | Value
   7          Park 1            1                71                 16        71
```

Some advice would be a huge blessing. I have been stuck on this for almost a full day now.

Thanks SO!

Comment: This problem can best be addressed by object oriented programming. Arrays and Datatables are nice as an intermediary step, but they make code harder to read/maintain if your core logic uses nothing but arrays. Explaning OOP is way beyond the scope of a single SO question. To help get you started: create a class (`MyClass`) that contains all field (cfr your datatable example), and then generate a `List<MyClass`.

Comment: OOP is not the problem. I am piling all this test code up in one class for testing.

Comment: Not trying to be facetious, but _lack of OOP_ is exactly your problem here. You have a repeatable set of objects (linekey) that all have the same set of properties, yet you are avoiding putting these in a class with separate properties. You're choosing the hard route for no discernible reason. Is there a reason why you're avoiding using classes for easier parsing?

Comment: I don't know... it's just what I do. I have a really strange way of keeping all my classes in a certain file/folder structure. I normally don't do something like this. But since this is a new area for me, I am just testing. All the linekey properties go to different controls, so i could first study reading through the .cfg file.

Comment: I have read your problem and actually I am little bit confused that what do you want i cant get you. As you are saying that you can easily store the config file value to dictionary then what is hindrance in your coding?

Comment: @MohdIsmailSiddiqui: OP is saying that he can store the values **line by line**, but not **index by index** (i.e. grouped by the index "linekey . **number**")

Comment: I'm setting up classes now. I may just happen to run into a fix while doing so lol. Flater talked me into it.

Comment: I don't believe creating named classes for such is a great idea. You want to use something like an `ExpandoObject` or a `Dictionary`. I usually prefer a `Dictionary` in such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing something like:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // define structure
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
        // ....
        dt.Columns.Add("ColumnN");
        // Add rows like this:
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Column1 value", "Column2 value", .. , "ColumnN value" });
```

---

**UPDATE: Full sample**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MdeLoadTest
{
    class DataRow
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public int Line { get; set; }
        public int PickupValue { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    class ParseData
    {
        private List<DataRow> rows;
        private int ReadSource(string file)
        {
            string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(file);


            rows = new List<DataRow>();
            string fieldInfo, fieldValue, fieldName;
            int lineNumber, oldLineNumber;
            string[] splitLine;
            string[] fieldInfoParts;
            oldLineNumber = -1;
            DataRow row = null;
            foreach (string line in fileLines)
            {

                splitLine = line.Split('=');
                fieldInfo = splitLine[0];                
                fieldValue = splitLine.Count() >0? splitLine[1]:null;
                fieldInfoParts = fieldInfo.Split('.');

                lineNumber = int.Parse(fieldInfoParts[1]);
                fieldName = fieldInfoParts[2];

                if(lineNumber != oldLineNumber)
                {
                    rows.Add(row);
                    row = new DataRow();
                    oldLineNumber = lineNumber;
                }
                switch (fieldName)
                {
                    case "label":
                        row.Label = fieldValue;
                        break;
                    case "line":
                        row.Line = int.Parse(fieldValue);
                        break;
                    case "pickup_value":
                        row.PickupValue = int.Parse(fieldValue);
                        break;
                    case "type":
                        row.Type = int.Parse(fieldValue);
                        break;
                    case "value":
                        row.Value = int.Parse(fieldValue);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception($"Unknown key:{fieldName}");
                }
            }
            if (oldLineNumber != -1)
            {
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return rows.Count;
        }

        DataTable table;
        private void InitTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // define structure
            dt.Columns.Add("Label",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PickupValue", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        }

        private void PopulateData ()
        {
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        public DataTable Load(string sourceFile)
        {
            if (ReadSource(sourceFile) < 1)
                return null;
            InitTable();
            PopulateData();

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that setup already. Problem is the linekey.INT.option. I have to be able to iterate through them. (the int)

Comment: if I understand you correctly your structure is: linekey.<rownumber>.<fieldName> = <fieldValue> ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want. I know, I know... I am not the best at communicating and explaining things.

Comment: choosing best answer because of the amount of work you put into this. I found a much much more simple way, but thanks :)

Comment: could you provide your final solution for the next person that will come along?

Answer (score 0):

I have written below a generic routine to parse the configuration you have. Needless to say, you will have to add boundary condition checks and do other testing on it. The code demonstrates how to parse a dotted format key from config and store it in an appropriate structure for easy retrieval later on.

```
class Configuration {
    Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> ParsedConfig = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();

    public Configuration(string fileName) {
        ParseConfig(File.ReadLines(fileName));
    }

    void ParseConfig(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
        foreach (string line in lines) {
            string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
            if (splitLine.Length != 2)
                continue;

            var cfgKey = splitLine[0].Trim();       // you probably want to get rid of trailing and leading spaces
            var cfgValue = splitLine[1].Trim();

            if (!cfgKey.Contains('.')) { // handle regular keys
                var singularList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                ParsedConfig[cfgKey] = singularList;
                singularList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
                singularList[0][string.Empty] = cfgValue;
                continue;
            }


            var keyParts = cfgKey.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 3); // break down the dotted key
            if (keyParts.Length != 3)
                continue;


            if (!ParsedConfig.TryGetValue(keyParts[0], out var indexedConfigList))
                ParsedConfig[keyParts[0]] = indexedConfigList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            var index = int.Parse(keyParts[1]);

            while (indexedConfigList.Count <= index) // add array slots for all indexes
                indexedConfigList.Add(null);

            var indexedConfig = indexedConfigList[index];
            if (indexedConfig == null)
                indexedConfigList[index] = indexedConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            indexedConfig[keyParts[2]] = cfgValue;
        }

    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetGroupedConfig(string key, int index) {
        if (ParsedConfig.TryGetValue(key, out var indexedConfigList) && indexedConfigList.Count > index)
            return indexedConfigList[index];

        return null;
    }

    public string GetConfigValue(string key) {
        string value = null;
        if (ParsedConfig.TryGetValue(key, out var indexedConfigList) && indexedConfigList.Count > 0)
            indexedConfigList[0].TryGetValue(string.Empty, out value);
        return value;
    }

}
```

The `Get*` methods demonstrate how to extract the values from the parsed configuration.

Now you can call the `Get*` functions and use the values as needed in your `DataTable`